# How to reply to a message using Gmail API in java?

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to reply to a message using the gmail api, and I am confused in setting the In-Reply-To and references header, I am not sure what to set the value to and how to set the value. Please find my code below:

```
public static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage emailContent) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    emailContent.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, emailContent.getFrom()[0]);
    emailContent.setReplyTo(emailContent.getFrom());
    emailContent.setHeader("In-Reply-To", emailContent.getMessageID());
    emailContent.setHeader("References",emailContent.getMessageID());
    emailContent.setText("hi thank you");
    emailContent.writeTo(buffer);
    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(bytes);
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
  }




private static Message replyMessage(Gmail service, String userId, MimeMessage emailContent,Message messages) throws Exception {
    Message message = createMessageWithEmail(emailContent);
    message.setThreadId(messages.getThreadId());
    message.setId(messages.getId());
    message = service.users().messages().send(userId, message).execute();
    System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
    System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
    return message;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these headers come from [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822).

The parts relevant to your question are included on pages 23-24 (emphasis and formatting mine):

> **When creating a reply to a message**, the "In-Reply-To:" and
> "References:" fields of the resultant message are constructed as
> follows:
>
> - **The "In-Reply-To:" field** will contain the contents of the "Message-ID:" field of the message to which this one is a reply (the "parent message").  If there is more than one parent message, then the "In-Reply-To:" field will contain the contents of all of the parents' "Message-ID:" fields.  If there is no "Message-ID:" field in any of the parent messages, then the new message will have no "In-Reply-To:" field.
> - **The "References:" field** will contain the contents of the parent's "References:" field (if any) followed by the contents of the parent's "Message-ID:" field (if any).  If the parent message does not contain a "References:" field but does have an "In-Reply-To:" field > containing a single message identifier, then the "References:" field will contain the contents of the parent's "In-Reply-To:" field followed by the contents of the parent's "Message-ID:" field (if any).  If the parent has none of the "References:", "In-Reply-To:", or "Message-ID:" fields, then the new message will have no "References:" field.

Comment: What is meant by contain the contents of the "Message-ID:" does that mean the message id in itself if that is the case i think I am adding it here emailContent.setHeader("In-Reply-To", emailContent.getMessageID());
emailContent.setHeader("References",emailContent.getMessageID());

Comment: @user2987322 yes, you are setting this values correctly. The points of these headers is to link the messages, for example in the same thread, although [GMail also uses `Subject` field for that purpose](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-gmail-decide-to-thread-email-messages).

Comment: i am not sure if i understand that.  sorry!

Comment: @user2987322 let's you have message A with id 42, then someone replies to that message with message B. That message B should have 42 set in both of the headers you are asking about, in order for mail clients to be able to correctly link the messages (i.e. understand that both come from the same thread).